# Не отображаются переменные в шаболне Django

Tags: django, переменные, шаблоны, include

Есть шаблон `template`, в котором используется подшаблон `menu`, вызываемый оператором `include`

**Шаблон template**:

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}
    {% block content %}
        {% include 'app/menu.html' %} <!-- Вставка menu -->
... html-код ...
```

Несмотря на определение в диспетчере URL обработчика шаблона "menu" ссылка на него использеуется только вышеописанным образом оператором `include`.

При передаче переменных из `views` отображается только переменная `staff`, связанная с моделью `user`.

> Непонятно, почему так происходит! И каким образом реализовать
>   отображение переменных через шаблон `menu` в данном случае?

**URL.py**:

```
... 
url(r'^menu/$', app.views.menu, name='menu'), 
...
```

**Views.py**:

```
def menu(request):
    staff = request.user.staff   
    A = 888 
    B = 555
    template = 'app/menu.html'

    return render(request, template, {'staff': staff, 'A': A, 'B': B, })
```

**menu.html:**

```
...
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li> 1:{{staff}}</li>
    <li> 2:{{A}}</li>                        
    <li> 3:{{B}}</li>
</ul>
...
```

В итоге имеем вывод только переменной `staff`:

```
1:Сотрудники ОТС
2:
3:
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. include в шаблонах не имеет абсолютно никакого отношения к URL. И где в показанном вами коде используется шаблон с include?

Comment: Добавил информации по шаблонам. Ситуация простая. На шаблон 'menu' есть view-обработчик, но переменные из него не отображаются в 'menu'. Возможно это связано с тем, что шаблон 'menu' вызывается оператором 'include', а не прямой ссылкой из 'template' и соответствующей обработкой через диспетчер URL.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаблон не имеет отношения к представлениям и `urls.py`.

Тег `{% include %}` просто склеивает шаблоны перед непосредственным рендерингом.
Следовательно, чтобы отобразить переменные, Вам нужно отрендерить шаблон `template`, передав весь необходимый контекст.

***Пример:***

```py
# То представление, которое обрабатывает template.html
def template_view(request):
    context = {
        'staff': request.user.staff,
        'A': 888,
        'B': 555,
    }

    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

Comment: А как обстоит дело с использованием тега {% block menu%}...menu...{%endblock%} вместо 'include'? Пробую заменить вставку menu с 'include' на {% block %}, а в качестве вызывающего использую шаблон 'template' - результат тот же - переменные не отображаются! Или в данном случае также необходимо рендерить 'template' контекстом 'menu'?

Comment: @JBlack Дело с тегом `{% block %}` обстоит также. Он никак не связан с представлением. Его задача примерно такая же, как и `{% include %}` - предоставить Вам единый шаблон. Эти теги по большей степени создавались для того, чтобы повторно использовать код и структурировать шаблоны. Рендерить необходимо точно также, то есть с контекстом `menu`.